# Error when trying to put objects in a method

Tags: java, class, methods, instance

Im trying to make a program that calculate the distanace by typying in two numbers.
I have created two objects a, b and want to send them to my method distance after i have given them a value but i get an error =(. How can I tackle this problem?
My code is presented below.

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Hey {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        num a = new num();
        num b = new num();
        String s1 = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Koordinateter för den frösta pinkten?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s1);
        a.num1 = sc.nextDouble();
        a.num2 = sc.nextDouble();

        String s2 = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Koordinateter för den frösta pinkten?");
        sc = new Scanner(s2);
        b.num1 = sc.nextDouble();
        b.num2 = sc.nextDouble();

        double d = distance(a, b);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Avstpbd: " + d);

    }

    public static double distance(num a, num b) {
        return Math.sqrt((a.num1 - a.num1) * (a.num1 - a.num1)
                + (b.num1 - b.num1) * (b.num1 - b.num1));
    }

    class num {
        double num1;
        double num2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? and where? please post that too.

Comment: `num` is inner class which means it is "member" of `Hey` class so you can use it only via instance of its outer class. Maybe you want to put it outside of `Hey` class? Other option to create instance of it without instance of outer class is to make it `static`.

Comment: Also please don't call your class `num`, call it `Num`. And `Hey` is a weird name of a class, consider changing it please.

Answer (score 2):

`num` class is inside the `Hey` class, so you need to call the num class object using the `Hey object`

[**Reference**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Do like this

```
Hey h=new Hey();
num a = h.new num();
num b = h.new num();
```